# How to get the number of rows returned MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query which I am getting the count of the number of songs clicked is it possible to get the number of rows returned? as my host doesn't allow query that take a long time so I was thinking to get the number of rows then run the query again and offset it to get the next 50 and so on

`SELECT mv.id, mv.songname, mv.slug, (SELECT Count(*) FROM clickedsongname WHERE clickedsongname.songid = mv.id) Count FROM videoname mv;`

I've tried doing this to get the count:

`SELECT count(*) mv.id, mv.songname, mv.slug, (SELECT Count(*) FROM clickedsongname WHERE clickedsongname.songid = mv.id) Count FROM videoname mv;`

and

`SELECT count(*) mv.id, mv.songname, mv.slug, (SELECT Count(*) FROM clickedsongname WHERE clickedsongname.songid = mv.id) Count FROM videoname mv as overallcount`

Answer (score 1):

You can use some built in PHP MySQLi functions.

```
#define the connection
$con = mysqli_connect("ip","user","pass","dbname");

#define the query
$query = '(query that gets rows)';

#run the query
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysql_error());

#Get the row count
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

print_r($rows);
```

Hope this helps!